# How do I repond to a BLE pairing request

Tags: windows, bluetooth-lowenergy

My (Windows) program makes BLE advertisements. My BLE devices can see this advertisement and connects to the PC. After the connection is established the BLE devices wishes to bond/pair. This request from my BLE device makes Windows show the "Add a device" dialog, which you can click (and the "Bluetooth & other devices" window is shown + the dialog "Pair device?" with a "Allow" + "Cancel" button).
What I want is to avoid this all along - when a BLE device connects to Windows I want the pairing process to be done without user interactions. How can I achieve that?

Note: this is NOT Windows connecting to a device. Here Windows ask for the pairing and the "background-pairing" is done by doing a custom pairing with a Custom_PairingRequested event handler doing a args.Accept().

Comment: 1. If your BLE device initiates p[pairing there is no easy way to handle such pairing requests inside your app. 2. If PC initiates pairing then you just need to disable authentication agent.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko 1: there is no easy way or it's impossible? (2: I can handle this - but it's 1 that is the problem)

Comment: 1. It is possible but not easy (and I can not share the method). 2. To disable authentication popups (in any case, does not matter which side initiates pairing) you have to disable authentication agent.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko No, you do not have to disable anything to avoid the notification message when windows connects and pairs to a device (that advertises). You just have to make a custom pairing. I got that working and you can find forums with the code I uses... But now the PC is the one advertising and my device that connects and the custom pairing code (+ event) are not called. And I can't initiate the connect+pairing because the device is not advertising ("invisible" to Windows).

Comment: It looks you know all the things better so It's up to you then.